# Wepback sourcemap not working properly on FF 54

Tags: firefox, webpack, source-maps

I have this [Webpack Config](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d73d21c9b887fa76a2b70d6113064a3)

Notice:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  sourceMap: true,
}),
```

and:

```
devtool: !PROD ? 'eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
```

I'm running a dev environment so in this case

```
devtool: 'eval-source-map'
```

I use firefox 54 with the following setting:

```
devtools.source-map.locations.enabled:true
```

When working with Chrome console I can easily debug from the console since the mapping works perfectly

[image: Chrome console]

And it takes me to the right line:

[image: Chrome source]

But when using firefox it gets the mapping wrong:

[image: Firefox console]

And always takes me to a wrong file and line (in this case a lodash.js line)

[image]

Is this a Firefox bug? Or there's something wrong with my webpack config?